adjusted residuals chi-square test of independence
I'm confused about what the value should be for adjusted residuals for chi-square test of independence. I requested adjusted residuals to see which combo drives the relationship for chi-square.
I know the cut-off is +/- 1.96. So, do in range or out of range values signify that a cell is contributing to the chi-square value?
I know positive values denote that the obs. freq is higher than the expected...
Also, negative values denote that the obs. freq is lower than the expected...
In other words, can adjusted residuals be interpreted similar to standardized residuals in that the larger the residual, the greater the contribution of the cell to the magnitude of the resulting chi-square obtained value?

I'm not sure I understand. Can you define "adjusted residual"? As an edit to the post, please!
